# Java Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java

```
package src.sheet1.question1;

class OneFourTwoOne {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        assert args.length == 1;

        int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        System.out.print(x);

        while(x != 1) {
            x = next(x);
            System.out.print(" " + x);
        };

    }

    static int next(int x) {

        return ((x % 2) == 0) ? (x / 2) : (3*x + 1);

    }

}
```

when I input :java OneFourTwoOne in the terminal, here occurs an error:
Error: Could not find or load main class OneFourTwoOne
How can I run it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java cannot run your class because it is in a package. Java expects the package name to be matched by the path to your file.

Create a directory structure that looks like this:

```
src
  +-sheet1
     +-question1
        +-OneFourTwoOne.java
```

and compile your class into `OneFourTwoOne.class`. Now switch the parent directory of `src`, and execute the command

```
java src.sheet1.question1.OneFourTwoOne
```

Answer (score 0):

Java cannot run your class because it is in a package. Java expects the package name to be matched by the path to your file.